# Is it possible to get a notification from Redis server in case a connected client disconnects?

Tags: redis

There are keyspace notifications in Redis. I'm looking for something similar but for connected clients. Does Redis have it built-in?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No it is not supported by default.
But there can be a work around for it.

You can create a key called `client-0` in redis with a `ttl` of 10 secs, And register a keyspace notification for this key. `client-0` should update the ttl in background continuously every 5 seconds, kind of a keep alive for the key. If `client-0` fails to update `ttl` and key expires you can assume the `client-0` is dead.

Answer (score 1):

No, Redis does not have that built-in.